# JavaScript wrap existing function in async one: deal with the result (automatically wrapped into a Promise)?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to write a "mixing" for JavaScript classes (controllers, in my app) to automatically "await" for a given function to be resolved, before actually invoke the real methods. Real class methods should receive the resolved value as last argument.

Here is the code of `useAwait`, where i'm looking for the static class property `awaits` and wrapping the `originalFunc` into a new `async` one. I'm calling the new function passing the original arguments *plus* the `asyncFn` call result:

```js
const useAwait = (controller, asyncFn) => {
  controller.constructor.awaits.forEach(func => {
    const originalFunc = controller[func];

    controller[func] = async (...args) => {
      return originalFunc.apply(
        controller,
        [...args, await asyncFn.call(controller)]
      );
    };
  });
}
```

So when `useAwait(ctrl, this.load)` is invoked on an instance this class:

```js
class Controller {
  static awaits = ['foo', 'bar'];
  
  promise;
  
  constructor() {
    useAwait(this, this.load);
  }
  
  async foo(e, resolved) {        
    return resolved;
  }
  
  bar(resolved) {
    return resolved;
  }
  
  async load() {
    if (!this.promise) {
      this.promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Hello World!');
      }, 3000));
    }

    return this.promise;
  }
}
```

The **problem**: all seems fine for `foo` (already `async`), but it's not for `bar`: the result is a `Promise` because now the `bar` is wrapped in `async` (wan't before). I know that an async function result is wrapped into a `Promise`. [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/JjLRYZG) where `bar` call outputs "[object Promise]".

So the **question** is: in theory, I should check if the original function is `async` and if  it was not, `await` for it's return value?

Comment: "*the result is a Promise because now*" - well you can't avoid that if you want to wait for `this.load()` before calling the real `bar`

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. In JavaScript a method without the async keyword will never wait for anything - it will just invoke all code right one line after the other and return. - So at the highest level, where you want to wait, before invoking another method you will need to write async and await right there (or use a Promise().then(...))

Comment: I don't understand what problem the `useAwait` is supposed to solve. What does `load()` do in your real code? And why do all of the controller's methods need to wait for it?

Comment: @Bergi legit question. The class in real code is a controller (MVC pattern controller). Controller can have multiple methods, each one eventually need an instance to work on. That instance is provided by the load () method. Instead of await for it in every method, I'd like to "inject" the resolved value.

Comment: @gremo Ah - don't do that. Use a static asynchronous `create` method, and construct the controller once the working instance is loaded, like suggested below in TJ Crowder's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not controlling how controller is created (framework does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...in theory, I should check if the original function is `async` and if it was not, `await` for it's return value?"

It wouldn't matter, your wrapper is `async`; an `async` function **always** returns a promise, whether you use `await` or not. Moreover, your wrapper **can't** be synchronous, because it needs to call `awaitFn` (`load`, in the example) and wait for its result.

If you're going to wrap `originalFunction` (`bar`) such that it waits for `awaitFn` (`load`) to complete, the wrapped version of it needs to be asynchronous (either `async`, or return a promise explicitly [or accept a callback, but better IMHO to use promises]). It cannot be synchronous, because `awaitFn` (`load`) isn't synchronous.

If the class instance isn't ready for use when you construct it, you might consider using a static method to get an instance instead; the static instance would return a promise that it fulfills with the instance once `load` is complete. Rough sketch:

```
class Controller {
    dataFromLoadingProcess;

    constructor(dataFromLoadingProcess) {
        this.dataFromLoadingProcess = dataFromLoadingProcess;
    }

    async foo(e, resolved) {
        // ...optionally use `this.dataFromLoadingProcess`...
        return resolved;
    }

    bar(resolved) {
        // ...optionally use `this.dataFromLoadingProcess`...
        return resolved;
    }

    static async createInstance() {
        await /*...the loading process...*/;
        return new Controller(/*...data from loading process here, perhaps...*/)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to solve the problem with bar I think. Do you agree, apart from the static method to get the instance..

Comment: @gremo - Yes. If you need to wait for `load` in the wrapped version of `bar`, the wrapped version of `bar` has to be asynchronous.

Comment: Then I guess i'll stick with limiting the mixing to async function and rename it to `useProvideAsyncResult`!